# How to get the coordinates of QR code using ZXing?

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I can get the value of the QR code using ZXing library but I also need the coordinates of the corner points of the QR code. How can I access those coordinates.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know exactly which corner coordinates you want to extract.
But I'm quite sure you can calculate them from the result points got from the
[Result.getResultPoints()](https://zxing.github.io/zxing/apidocs/com/google/zxing/Result.html#getResultPoints--) method.

Example: With the following image (200x200 pixels) and code snippet

[image: QRCode]

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("QRCode-1.png"));
BinaryBitmap binaryBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(
        new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(image)));
Reader reader = new QRCodeReader();
Result result = reader.decode(binaryBitmap);
System.out.println("text: " + result.getText());
ResultPoint[] resultPoints = result.getResultPoints();
System.out.println("resultPoints:");
for (int i = 0; i < resultPoints.length; i++) {
    ResultPoint resultPoint = resultPoints[i];
    System.out.print("  [" + i + "]:");
    System.out.print(" x = " + resultPoint.getX());
    System.out.print(", y = " + resultPoint.getY());
    if (resultPoint instanceof FinderPattern)
        System.out.print(", estimatedModuleSize = "
                + ((FinderPattern) resultPoint).getEstimatedModuleSize());
    System.out.println();
}
```

I get this output:

```
text: Hello World!
resultPoints:
  [0]: x = 36.5, y = 162.5, estimatedModuleSize = 9.0
  [1]: x = 36.5, y = 36.5, estimatedModuleSize = 9.0
  [2]: x = 162.5, y = 36.5, estimatedModuleSize = 9.0
```

`x` and `y` are the center coordinates of the square finder patterns.
Knowing that the [QRCode finder patterns](http://qrcode.meetheed.com/question14.php) have size of 7x7 modules,
you can easily calculate the corner coordinates.

Comment: This code works well when the  QR code occupies large part of  the image.  The QR code I want to scan is on the top left corner of a page and is not very big so the code is not able to detect it.Can you suggest some solution for this.

Comment: @PrakharGanesh Now that is an entirely different issue.
May be your `QRCodeReader` works better when you add the 
[TRY_HARDER](https://zxing.github.io/zxing/apidocs/com/google/zxing/DecodeHintType.html#TRY_HARDER) decode hint.

Comment: what represents the estimatedModuleSize? the square on this QR are very symmetric but I have found some QR codes where the squares finder are smaller that the space in between them.. I am not so sure how to find the corners on that case, I am thinking that the estimatedModuleSize maybe can help there, but how?

Comment: @delkant The "modules" are the small elementary black or white squares of the QR-code. In the shown example image each module has size of 9x9 image pixels. (Just open the image in an image editor and count the pixels.)

Comment: One more word, the finder pattern has a width ratio of 1:1:3:1:1 (black vs white). That is, the black square in the center has width of `3*moduleSize` pixels.